# network goes off

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, dns

My internet goes off intermittently (OS: Ubuntu 16.04). The issue seems to be with DNS.

When I go to `vim /etc/resolv.conf` as root and add `8.8.8.8` so `resolv.conf` is as below, the problem resolves temporarily (though the internet browsing is slow); but after a while, the internet stops again and I need to restart my PC.

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in 16.04 (and possibly earlier/later versions). I've experienced it myself on every other Ubuntu 16.04 install.

I have found that the easiest way to fix it is to add name servers manually, although not through the resolv.conf file, as your changes will be overwritten.

If you're on a desktop, open Network Connections and select one your network interface. Then navigate to "IPv4 Settings" (assuming you're on a IPv4 network) and set the DNS to 8.8.8.8, or another DNS server of your liking.

[image]

If you're on a server installation (without DE), edit the /etc/network/interfaces file directly, and add the name server to your interface.

Example:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
         address 192.168.1.100
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         broadcast 192.168.1.255
         dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```